# Radar Camera Extrinsic Calibration and Fusion

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-18.04, ros, homography, sensor-fusion

I am trying to do multi-sensor calibration and fusion on ROS. I have already completed Lidar-camera calibration and fusion using the Rotation and translation vectors found using opencv functions.

But I am confused in the radar-camera calibration. I have read on some papers to use homography matrix since the radar has only x and y values(z = 0). The points projected to image using homography are not accurate.
Do i need to convert the radar coordinate axis to image coordinate axis before finding homography ?

Am I missing anything? Can anyone explain an accurate process so that i can project radar points to image?

Note: I have done clustering on the pointcloud and the centroids of these clusters are published for using it on projection.

Comment: Dynamically project the 3D radar points to the camera image. The bigger the distance between the camera and radar sensors, the less likely a static mapping like homography or shift can work.

Comment: @Micka thankyou for answering. I'm still confused tho. What do you mean by "dynamically projecting the radar points " ? For projecting the points I should multiply them with a projection matrix or homography matrix right ?

Comment: you will need extrinsics and intrinsics of the camera (which gives you a projection from scene to image). When you have the extrinsics of your radar sensor, you can "project" the radar points to the scene and from there you can project to the image. Is it right that you are basically asking "how to get extrinsics of camera and radar in the same global coordinate system?"?

Comment: Yes @Micka I already have the camera intrinsics. I need radar camera extrinsics

Comment: for camera extrinsics you can place any known object in the scene  and use solvePnp to get the object pose relative to the camera. Invert that to get the camera pose relative to the object. So if you place a cube in the scene where you want to have the 3D space origin, pose it with axes along your wanted 3D space axes and read the image points and use solvePnp + invert. Then you have the extrinsics relative to your now definied 3D space coordinate system. If you can use the same cube for your radar measurements you can find the radar extrinsics in that coordinate system.

Comment: your "cameras" do not have a common optical center. hence homography is insufficient. you need to know the extrinsics, i.e. the transformation between origins. then you need to transform your point cloud from the lidar frame into the camera frame. then you can project those onto the image plane.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I did clustering on the pointcloud and then selected 16 corresponding points. I tried these points on the cv2.solvepnpransac function to find the rotation and translation matrices. The Translation vector values are very large and hence projection is also wrong !!  https://github.com/heethesh/lidar_camera_calibration this is the code i used for reference